# Buscar cadena con 2 dígitos constantes y que le sigan 8 dígitos más

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito de una cadena de texto filtrar las que contienen el siguiente formato:

```
   SELECT Referencia FROM A 
   WHERE Referencia LIKE '%[78][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Donde el `78` es un número fijo y necesito que le sigan exactamente 8 caracteres numéricos.

Ejemplo de Cadenas:

> PLANO-7800002154_asdvd0.pdf
>
> TOMO_1800015711.pdf
>
> 2016032213_Campo_AS.pdf

**Solo quiero que me devuelva el que tiene 78XXXXXXXX**

Y después obtener solo esa cadena de números.

Comment: `[78]` es el carácter `7` u  `8`, por lo que dices debiera ser '%78[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'

Comment: Haciendo eso no me filtra por los que empiezan en 78. yo creo que el error está en esto '%78[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'

Comment: el 78 esta siempre en el mismo lugar? es una cadena que se puede considerar estandar? siempre tiene el mismo formato? yo agregaria mas ejemplos de cadenas posibles...

Comment: Ahí agregue otros ejemplos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `like` debería ser por `'%78[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'` (el `78` sin los paréntesis rectos).

Para verificarlo con los ejemplos que aparecen en la pregunta, esta consulta:

```
select val
from (
    select 'PLANO-7800002154_asdvd0.pdf' as val
    union
    select 'TOMO_1800015711.pdf'
    union
    select '2016032213_Campo_AS.pdf'
    ) as T
where val like '%78[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

devuelve solamente el registro buscado.

La consulta con el `like` como estaba originalmente:

```
select val
from (
    select 'PLANO-7800002154_asdvd0.pdf' as val
    union
    select 'TOMO_1800015711.pdf'
    union
    select '2016032213_Campo_AS.pdf'
    ) as T
where val like '%[78][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

devuelve también el valor `TOMO_1800015711.pdf`

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos. Me sabrias decir como sacar la cadena de 10 digitos cuando esta en el medio del string? `PLANO-**7800002154**_asdvd0.pdf`

Comment: En relaidad necesito conseguir esos 10 caracteres pero para los 3 casos. `PLANO-7800002154_asdvd0.pdf` /*/

`TOMO_1800015711.pdf`/*/

`2016032213_Campo_AS.pdf`/*/

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(val,patindex('%[1-9]%',val),10) as Substr
FROM (
    SELECT 'PLANO-7800002154_asdvd0.pdf' AS val
    UNION
    SELECT 'TOMO_1800015711.pdf'
    UNION
    SELECT '2016032213_Campo_AS.pdf'
    ) AS T
```

`Patindex` busca la primera posición que cumpla con los criterios asignados en una cadena, de ahí el `substring` devuelve una cadena de la posición inicial en este caso el `patindex` y 10 posiciones si requieres los 78 la puedes combinar con el `where` que te indicaron.